# How to limit wordpress menu depth in admin panel

Tags: theme-development, menus, admin-menu

Is it possible to limit maximum menu depth in admin panel `/nav-menus.php`?

I need this because my theme won't support more than two levels of menu, so there is no point in allowing a user to make deeper menus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow up on @jmarceli's and @squarecandy's great answers. Here is a solution that allows for:

- Easier scaling (set an object in the php action)
- Updates to the correct menu depth when the location checkboxes are changed

```
/**
 * Limit max menu depth in admin panel 
 */

function limit_admin_menu_depth($hook)
{
    if ($hook != 'nav-menus.php') return;

    wp_register_script('limit-admin-menu-depth', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin/limit-menu-depth.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_localize_script(
        'limit-admin-menu-depth',
        'myMenuDepths',
        array(
            'primary' => 1, // <-- Set your menu location and max depth here
            'footer' => 0 // <-- Add as many as you like
        )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('limit-admin-menu-depth');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'limit_admin_menu_depth' );
```

js

```
/**
 * Limit max menu depth in admin panel
 * Expects wp_localize_script to have set an object of menu locations
 * in the shape of { location: maxDepth, location2: maxDepth2 }
 * e.g var menu-depths = {"primary":"1","footer":"0"};
 */
(function ($) {
    // Get initial maximum menu depth, so that we may restore to it later.
    var initialMaxDepth = wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth;

    function setMaxDepth() {
        // Loop through each of the menu locations
        $.each(myMenuDepths, function (location, maxDepth) {
            if (
                $('#locations-' + location).prop('checked') &&
                maxDepth < wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth
            ) {
                // If this menu location is checked
                // and if the max depth for this location is less than the current globalMaxDepth
                // Then set globalMaxDepth to the max depth for this location
                wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = maxDepth;
            }
        });
    }

    // Run the function once on document ready
    setMaxDepth();

    // Re-run the function if the menu location checkboxes are changed
    $('.menu-theme-locations input').on('change', function () {
        wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = initialMaxDepth;
        setMaxDepth();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is a wonderful solution/improvement. This is why I love Stack Exchange — over time, answers just keep getting better. Thanks for sharing! Just gotta upvote this so people see it sooner.

Comment: Hi buddy. Great that the solution has helped you. And, yes indeed, I too value the sharing and iteration of ideas here. ✌️

Answer (score 13):

The solution that I came up with:

```
/**
 * Limit max menu depth in admin panel to 2
 */
function q242068_limit_depth( $hook ) {
  if ( $hook != 'nav-menus.php' ) return;

  // override default value right after 'nav-menu' JS
  wp_add_inline_script( 'nav-menu', 'wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 1;', 'after' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'q242068_limit_depth' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow up on @jmarceli's great answer to target specific menu locations

```
function squarecandy_menu_admin_limit_depth( $hook ) {
  if ( 'nav-menus.php' !== $hook ) {
    return;
  }

  wp_enqueue_script( 'squarecandy-admin-menu-depth', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin-menu-depth.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'squarecandy_menu_admin_limit_depth' );
```

js

```
// Force Menu Depth to Match Front End

// main menu can only have one child level
if ( document.getElementById("locations-main-menu").checked ) {
    wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 1;
}

// footer menu have only top level
if ( document.getElementById("locations-footer-menu").checked ) {
    wpNavMenu.options.globalMaxDepth = 0;
}

// all other menu locations stay at the WP default
```

Comment: Nice solition, ty. I noticed a minor mistake:  `get_stylesheet_directory()` should be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.
Hope you don't mind but I made a few improvements, see my answer in case you're interested.

Comment: Good call, thanks @Davey. I edited it.